# Something's sending out emails but I can't find out what

Tags: email, workflow, tasks, customsetting, lead-conversion

I have a repeating issue that something is sending out e-mails and I can't figure out what. The e-mail contains a simple notification with a Link to a task created.

I have confirmed from the logs that the org was sending them out.
The e-mail does not match any e-Mail template, there is no email alert that mathes it, none of the standard things are a pure negative.

My question is, ... This is happening only during a Lead conversion process. Both the lead and Task have the e-mails's user set as owner. Is it possible, that there is a default functionality to automatically send out the e-mail, during the task creation or lead conversion process, to the RecordOwner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Apex lead conversion code there is indeed an option for email to the lead owner. However it is by default false.

See `setSendNotificationEmail(sendEmail)`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_convertLead.htm

How that is manipulated in the UI I don't know I'm afraid.

Possibly - Settings - Customize -> Lead Settings -> Notify Default Lead Owner

Comment: that was it, .... THNX

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue also and it turned out the email was being triggered by the queue in the object. Just went to setup > queues and then the recipients were there. I know this is an old post, so I am sure you are not still looking for the answer to this, but, it might help someone else.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).